# uitabview delegate method never called

Tags: iphone

I have a subclass of uiviewcontroller,and implemented the delegate UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.my code like:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) { 
    }
    return self;
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _listname=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cu",@"al",@"zn",@"au",@"ru",@"fu",@"rb",@"pb",@"wr", nil];       
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Source Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{     
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return [_listName count];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return TABLE_HEIGHT;
}
```

I have set the breakpoints,and the delegate method is never called.what's the problem?

Comment: Did you actually set the datasource and delegate in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the tableView delegate and data source to self

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

and implement the method (returning at least 1)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Comment: where I should add the code  tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;?thank you

Comment: either in viewDidLoad (the tableView must not be nil or the assignment will have no effect) or you can make the connections in interface builder.

Comment: I intend to create a IBOutlet myTableView,and connect myTableView to interface builder,how do you think?

Comment: If you haven't made an IBOutlet yet, is your tableView even initialized? Log it to check NSLog(@"tableView is : %@", tableView); If it's nil then it clearly won't be calling its dadaSource.

Comment: you are right,I just builded the connection in interface builder,thank you.